# Delay before starting download of pdf file using DownloadFile C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to download a large 25 megabyte pdf file using the following code:

```
string url = "http://aaa.aaa/test.pdf";
string clientfile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/123.pdf");
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), clientfile);
```

However the file signature is corrupted and does not download correctly.  Is there a way to delay the file download before the download actually starts?

I know the file is correct since if I download it from a browser, the file is not corrupted.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think a delay will help? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Mason thanks for your help.  I think a delay will help because it looks like it is generating the pdf on the fly when it is requested.  Thank you.

Comment: If it was generating on the fly when it was requested, then unless they had a *really* strange server, it would still generate in the same HTTP request. Adding a delay in your own code wouldn't really be a solution. It's far more likely they're doing some sort of request filtering to prevent the file from being downloaded without some sort of precondition being satisfied - like having a certain cookie or being authenticated etc.

Comment: Mason, nope its actually not authenticated (its http) and also I can download it without any cookie in the browser.  It's just the DownloadFile method that will not work.

Comment: Being HTTP has nothing to do with authentication. What does the resulting file look like? Have you tried opening it with a text or hex editor and inspecting it?

Comment: Yes I have.  It is missing the beginning PDF signature completely.  Although the file size is very close to the original correct file.  Thanks.

Comment: Apart from missing the PDF signature, is it a binary file? Or is it a text file?

Comment: It is definitely a binary file and about the same size (25 megs).  But the data is different from when you use a browser to download it.

Comment: Can we see an example of a bad pdf vs a good one?

Comment: Then I suggest you use Fiddler or a similar tool to compare requests being sent from your app and from the browser and spot the difference. The website doesn't really know whether a browser or your application is the one requesting the file, because the only things it can know are based on the actual HTTP request being sent. So compare the requests and spot the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  When downloading a pdf file, it is actually zipped in a format called "GZIP".  When using a browser, the file is automatically unzipped for the client.  When using the WebClient DownloadFile method in .NET, it must be done manually.  First create a class to derive the WebClient class as follows:

```
public class GzipWebClient : WebClient
    {
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            return request;
        }
    }
```

Then change your code to use the above class:

```
string url = "http://aaa.aaa/test.pdf";
string clientfile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/123.pdf");
GzipWebClient wc = new GzipWebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), clientfile);
```

The pdf file will now be correctly downloaded and unzipped automatically.